# Creating tick boxes with each item in array?

Tags: java

I have to make a mock up Amazon website style program in Windows Builder.

I have an array

```
String [] contents = {"book 1"..};
```

As a mock up database to simulate an item list, when an item is search such as book 1, i want to display on the screen "Book 1 []" [] being a check box.

Is there a way to create them via run time?

Im currently on mobile so possibly not the greatest explanation.

Comment: yes there should be ways to create them at runtime

Comment: What you're asking requires a longer and more complex answer than can be given on this website. If you read the appropriate documentation, try something and then run into a specific problem, post the code and error message and then it will be possible to give you advice.